# How important is it to enable read repair in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

If I understand it correctly, upon a write request the write is sent to all N replicas, and the operation succeeds when the first W responses are received. Is this correct?

If it is, then combined with Hinted Handoff, it seems that all replicas will already get all writes as soon as possible, do we really have to do read repair in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: you still need read repair.

Longer answer: there wasn't a good discussion of Hinted Handoff anywhere, so [I wrote one](http://www.datastax.com/2011/05/understanding-hinted-handoff).

For Cassandra 1.0+, read [the updated article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/modern-hinted-handoff). The crucial part being:

> At first glance, it may appear that Hinted Handoff lets you safely get away without needing repair. This is only true if you never have hardware failure.

Comment: Nice writeup. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for hinted handoff to fail for various reasons.  Such as the node the hint was written to can fail.  With read repair enabled if hinted handoff doesn't work for some reason read repair will fix it.  And then you should also run "nodetool repair" on your nodes to catch any cases where read repair and hinted handoff both fail to fix all the data.

Check the wiki for more info.

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/AntiEntropy

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HintedHandoff

Answer (score 1):

The consistency level can be varied for each write (and read).

For example, let's say we have 10 nodes, with a replication factor of 3.

But if we write with a consistency level of ANY, none of the eventual 3 replicas may initally have the data when the write call returns. If we use consistency level ONE, then only one of the eventual 3 replicas has to have the data before the write returns, so a read straight after the write may see outdated data *if* the read has a low consistency level.

See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API for the definitions of the consistency levels, particularly the following:

> Read level ONE: Will return the record
>   returned by the first replica to
>   respond. A consistency check is always
>   done in a background thread to fix any
>   consistency issues when
>   ConsistencyLevel.ONE is used. This
>   means subsequent calls will have
>   correct data even if the initial read
>   gets an older value. (This is called
>   ReadRepair)

See also http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ReadRepair :

> Read repair means that when a query is
>   made against a given key, we perform a
>   digest query against all the replicas
>   of the key and push the most recent
>   version to any out-of-date replicas.
>   If a low ConsistencyLevel was
>   specified, this is done in the
>   background after returning the data
>   from the closest replica to the
>   client; otherwise, it is done before
>   returning the data.

Comment: But if a write request has already been sent to each of these replicas, and these machines are so busy that these requests haven't been processed when a read comes, how would sending the same write request again via read repair help? As to node failures, they are already handled by hinted handoff, and the failed nodes will get the writes as soon as they're up again.

Comment: The write request *hasn't* necessarily been sent to the extra replicas yet, if the write consistency level is low. If your write is configured to use a high consistency level, then I'd agree with you...but both read and write in Cassandra can use a variety of consistency settings.

Comment: Do you mean that a write with a low CL may not be sent to all N replicas by the proxy node? This was my original question. For example, if N=10, W=1, the write may just be sent to 3 replicas? But wouldn't this decrease availability of the system? As if the 3 replica nodes are all down but there are still other replica nodes up, the write will fail unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes - I have edited my answer to (hopefully) expand on this point. Yes, some settings will reduce availability (but increase consistency). Some settings do the opposite - that's the advantage of the tunable consistency levels.